# Spring jpa date getReference (getOne) by unique field

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity have relational with other entity without cascade something like this :

```
@Entity
public class User {

    //id
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //fields
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Address> addressList;

}
```

and this entity :

```
@Entity
public class Address{

    //id
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //fields
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String location;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;

}
```

in this example i want to create Address without re get user from db and use jpa getReference but i dont have id of user and just username how to call SpringJpaData getOne() by unique field like username ?
is there better option to create new address without get user from db ?

Comment: User is the owner of the association. It's the user table (and thus the user entity) that must be modified to associate an avatar with the user. So you can't use a reference to the user. You need to actually load it and modify it.

Comment: @JBNizet my example is very bad .
in this example yes but somewhere not modified main entity how to get refrence ?

Comment: Without the ID, you can't. A reference is only useful because it contains the ID of the entity, which can thus be used to populate a join column (foreign key) to this entity. If you only have the name, you can't do anything, since you need the ID.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for reply 
is there any way to create entity without query to db ?

Comment: There is one: getReference(). But it needs the ID. If you want the ID, and you only have the name, how could anyone know what the ID is without querying the DB?